# How to check if Form is valid, without triggering error on TextFields

Tags: flutter

I'm using `formKey?.currentState?.validate()` to validate form. It also returns if Form is valid or not. But it reports results to the UI, by putting TextFormFields in error state(red underline etc.)

I want to check if Form is valid, **without** turning textfields to red/reporting result to UI. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Replacing your validators on methods can do the trick. This means you don't need to use the Form widget for this.

```dart
 final nameController = TextEditingController();

  String? nameValidation() {
    if (nameController.text.isEmpty) {
      return "Please enter name";
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  void onSubmit() async {
    /// now call every validation function
    final nameValidationResult = nameValidation();
    if (nameValidationResult != null) {
      /// show error
      return; // return so that it won't go to next step
    }

    ///....others validation

    /// at the end , it will go to next step
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        TextFormField(controller: nameController),
        ElevatedButton(onPressed: onSubmit, child: const Text("Submit")),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Makes sense and I'm starting to refactor with controllers. Is it possible to attach the error text to text editing controller during validation? I know I've asked the question based on "not showing the red error text" but since with controllers I'll validate one by one.

Comment: on current method, you can show dialog and return. As for the form, not showing error border can be archive by overriding `errorBorder`  of TextFormFiled decoration